# Why can't perl locate a module that exists in @INC?

Tags: perl, strawberry-perl

I've been running a perl script from python successfully for a while. I've just moved everything to a new computer (both are running Windows 10) and I'm running into issues.

When running the script I get the error:

```
Can't locate DBI.pm in @INC (you may need to install the DBI module) (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/share/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/core_perl /usr/share/perl5/core_perl)
```

On the first line `use DBI;`.

I moved to using `Perl (command line)`, selected the folder with the script and ran `perl <filename>` - same error.

`DBI` seems to be installed correctly in `C:\Strawberry\perl\vendor\lib` and that directory is in my `@INC` when I check via `perl -V`:

```
  @INC:
    C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib
    C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib
    C:/Strawberry/perl/lib
```

I've tried installing `DBI` again using `cpan Module::DBI` but I get the error:

```
Could not expand [Module::DBI]. Check the module name.
```

I've tried installing it with `perl -MCPAN -e "install Bundle::DBI"` but it fails with:

```
Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/original.t (Wstat: 0 Tests: 27 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  26
Files=1, Tests=27,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.05 usr +  0.01 sys =  0.06 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/1 test programs. 1/27 subtests failed.
gmake: *** [Makefile:863: test_dynamic] Error 255
  NEILB/IO-Tee-0.65.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\gmake.exe test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports NEILB/IO-Tee-0.65.tar.gz
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'IO::Tee'.
```

I didn't have any issues when setting things up on my previous machine (both times it has just been a vanilla install with no importing of additional modules).

I've tried reinstalling Strawberry a couple of times to no avail. I've tried installing perlbrew and ActivePerl but hit issues with both of those. I've also now exhausted Google for potential solutions.

Any ideas?

---

**Edit:**

Following the advice [here](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/perl/checking-testing-perl-module-in-inc-include-path/) I have run `perl -e "use DBI;"` and there is no error message which apparently means `DBI` is installed correctly?

---

**Edit 2**

Ok so I've managed to get things working via `Perl (command line)` and also via Windows `cmd` - it took a complete reinstall of MySQL which doesn't really make any sense but anyways. However, I still can't execute the script using `Git Bash`. I get the same error as always...

Comment: Re "*I've tried installing DBI again using `cpan Module::DBI`*", Yeah, that's because there's no such module. To install DBI, you want `cpan DBI`. There's also a pseudo-module named Bundle::DBI which has DBI and other modules as dependencies, causing those all of those to be installed. This is what you ended up trying to install using the second command.

Comment: Re "*Following the advice here I have run perl -e "use DBI;" and there is no error message which apparently means DBI is installed correctly?*" yes, for that `perl`

Comment: Re "*However, I still can't execute the script using Git Bash.*", Probably because you are using a `perl` built for that unix emulation environment instead of the Strawberry Perl build for which you installed the module

Comment: Hi. I've definitely only got one installation of Perl and that's Strawberry - I uninstalled/deleted ActiveState and perlbrew

Comment: No. When you installed git, you installed a whole unix emulation environment that includes bash, perl and other tools needed by git.

Comment: Ah - with you. Is there a way to fix my issue?

Comment: Yeah, use the correct perl. You can still access and execute programs that are outside of the msys unix emulation environment form within

Comment: Afraid I'm pretty new to all this and bar the script in question I've never used perl. I think I'm going to need the beginner explanation :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Perl. To run a program, you specify which program you want to run, so `C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl` or whatever is appropriate within MSYS. (Alternatively, you can make sure that SP's `perl` is before the other `perl` in the PATH env var in order to simply use `perl`, but that might break things.)

Comment: With you. I guess there's one way to find out...

Comment: Sorry - forgot to say thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

[ **Update: Bug fixed in IO-Tee 0.66.** ]

The failing test assumes that `sysread` obeys the `:crlf` layer that's added to file handles in Windows. But it doesn't. This is a bad test, not a problem with the module. As such, since that's the only failing test, you can safely force the installation of the module using the following:

```
cpan -f IO::Tee
```

Forcing the installation of a module with failing tests is normally a bad idea because it means you're forcing the installation of a module that's likely broken. But it's ok here because it has been established that the problem is with the test, not the module itself.

I have filed a [bug report](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=133156) with a more thorough explanation of the problem and a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've installed ```DBI``` via the method above and it updated to ```1.643```. Still getting same ```Can't locate```... error message. Ran ```cpan -f IO::Tee``` - that fails again and makes no difference to the ```Can't locate```... error :( Not sure if it's relevant but I've added the rest of the error message I get above - the directory references look weird but seem to broadly match?

Comment: I don't think that's true. `cpan -f` will still show the failing test, but it will install the module nonetheless. Once that module is installed you need to run `cpan DBI` or `cpan Bundle::DBI` again.  If you have further different problems, that's for another question (since we know nothing about them)

Comment: The bug has been fixed in the latest release.